# Jasmine preview site with angular 2 cli

Tags: angular, jasmine, command-line-interface, karma-runner

I am very new to jasmine testing with Angular 2 CLI and writing my first tests following the testing guide on angular.io.

When I go to the live examples on plunker all the test results are shown very nice in index.html, but when I run tests with my angular CLI application, the browser is opening Karma from where I can click the debug button. Doing this my next step is to click F12 for Developer tools console.

Here I can see the results of all my tests together with console logs, and it does not give me a very clear overview, specially when I soon will run a lot of tests.

I am sure that I am missing some information about this, but I have not be able to find more about it.

All guides that I found are doing som few tests and running them in the console, but in the case that I have to test a big application, there must be another way to have a nice overview without other console information in between.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you running a test on component for example the test creating the template of the component.

it making you to be able to click button or check how much element you have in *ngFor directive.

You can get element by:

```
let myComponentElement = fixture.nativeElement
```

you can use element to test your element for example:

the button:

```
<button id="my-test-button" (click)="myTestFunction()>ClickMe</button>
```

testing of the button:

```
it("click on my_test_button should call myTestFunction() ", ()=> {
  spyOn(componentInstance.myTestFunction);
  let my_test_button = myComponentElement.querySelector("my-test-button")
  my_test_button.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(componentInstance.myTestFunction).toHaveBeenCall();
})
```

last thing, you can actually see you testing template by put 'dubugger' on your test and click 'f12' on chrome.

for example:

```
 it("click on my_test_button should call myTestFunction() ", ()=> {
      spyOn(componentInstance.myTestFunction);
      let my_test_button = myComponentElement.querySelector("my-test-button")
      **debugger;**
      my_test_button.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(componentInstance.myTestFunction).toHaveBeenCall();
    })
```

you shuold see your component template when debugging.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thank you for answering YairTawil, but that is not the problem. My spec files are running well, but I would like to see them like the preview on this page and not in the console:
https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview&show=app%2F1st.spec.ts